# SVG clip-path url() syntax

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a d3 drawing with some clipPaths, then on certain svg elements, like on a rect I define a clip-path as

```
this.svgContainer.append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', this.maxHeight)
        .attr('clip-path', `url(#${this.options.selectionAreaClipId})`)
        .classed('selectionArea', true);
```

My question would be where can I read about what possible values can I put into "url()". I read about url, and uri but nowhere do they mention #id or anything close to this. I mean, can I define the clip with anything but an actual id?

Comment: The `url()` should/would contain the `id` of the `clipPath` tag within it. That is the syntax. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: Hi, I would like to find different approaches where I don't need to add an id to the clip but identify it somehow different. like #parent > clip-path.someClass, or i would be happy to read about my options :)

Comment: You can't do anything like that.  It has to be a URI. Most commonly it is a "fragment" - i.e. a "#" followed by an element id.

Comment: it's a fragment/id but there's nothing stopping you from getting the element by class (select) and then getting its id, Like `this.svgContainer.select(".someClass").attr('id')`. This is useful when the id is autogenerated.